# on complete and on success both together are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, fancybox

i am trying to use on `success` and `complete` together but its not working,
if i am not using `dataType: "jsonp"` then `Success` work if i include this then on `complete` works

```
 var reRank=false;
    function reAssign() {
    if (!reRank){
        reRank = true;
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data : {
                "id" : $("#boxId").val(),
                "value" : $("#hidValue").val()
            },
            url : "/ajax/save",
            complete : function() {
                reRank = false;
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.fancybox(data, {
                    closeClick : false,
                    helpers : {
                        overlay : {
                            closeClick : false
                        }
                    }
                });

                alert(obj.result);
            }
        });
    }
}// end reAssign
```

Comment: And you're sure the issue isn't just asynchronicity, the `reRank` variable looks hinky !

Comment: Parsing JSON data that is already parsed will give you an error.

Comment: Well, still, when you set the datatype to jsonp it's already parsed, `JSON.parse` probably gets you an error. Learn how to use the console (F12).

Comment: @adeno yes that was because of parsing Json again, really thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to track the ajax request through the `Network` tab of developer tools. Also add the following to track the errors.

```
...
error: function ( error ) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(error));
}
...
```

Most probably, the request will be failing because of some server side issue. If that's the case `success` will never get called, however `complete` (which is called whenever an ajax request completes no matter with error or without error) always gets called.